# Unable to start Oracle (11g1) due to bad memory configuration (ORA-00837)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, memory

I decided to reduce the memory allocation of a local developer instance, and was told that the following command did the job;

```
alter system set memory_max_target = 512M scope = spfile;
```

Which I guess it did, since I no longer can start the Oracle instance in question. This is the error I get when trying to connect as a non-DBA-user;

```
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

When connecting as SYSDBA I get the following;

```
Connected to an inactive instance.
SQL>startup nomount;
ORA-00837: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET greater than MEMORY_MAX_TARGET
SQL>alter system set memory_max_target = 2G scope = spfile;
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
```

*("Connected to an inactive instance." is my translation of a localized error message, might not be exactly correct)*
So, I'm in a catch 22 situation, I can't change the memory parameters without starting up, and I can't start up.

Is there a way to change these parameters offline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you start your instance using a server parameter file (a binary version of initialization parameter file, spfile), you can extract the initialization parameters to plain-text initialization parameter file (pfile), alter them, and then start your instance with modified memory parameters.

```
sql> create pfile='myinit.ora' from spfile='spfileORCL.ora';
```

Modify your memory-related parameters in `myinit.ora` and start your instance using this new configuration:

```
sql> startup pfile='myinit.ora';
```

You can then save your settings back to an spfile with the following command:

```
sql> create spfile='spfileORCL.ora' from pfile='myinit.ora';
```

And start your database as usual:

```
sql> startup;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. The only change I needed to do on my side was to replace ORCL with the SID of the instance in question. I set the memory_target-parameter to the same value as the memory_max_target-parameter, which might not be optimal, but it made it possible to start.

Comment: Yep, the names of the spfiles Oracle tries to start with are `spfileSID.ora` and `spfile.ora`, then it tries to read from pfile `init.ora` if no spfiles found. By the way `MEMORY_MAX_TARGET` may well be many times greater than `MEMORY_TARGET` though it cannot be modified dynamically – the instance needs to be bounced.

Comment: Oops, it's `initSID.ora` actually, not `init.ora`.

Answer (score 1):

The early 11gR1 releases has this bug. They won't start if the memory_target was set to 2GB (and more). Either upgrade to 11gR2 (or 11.1.0.7) or use "classical" SGA/PGA parameters(sga_target, sga_max_size, pga_aggregate_target).

Comment: How this is related to "ORA-00837: Specified value of MEMORY_TARGET greater than MEMORY_MAX_TARGET" the OP notes about?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using linux OS: have you checked size of /dev/shm filesystem?  The size of this fs must be long enough to fit your SGA.  If not, try remounting with '-o size=xxx'.

Comment: Did you ever read the cause of the failure which is identified by Oracle error number in OP (ORA-00837)?